# Why can't we access local variable inside rescue?

Tags: ruby

Local Variable

```
begin
  transaction  #Code inside transaction 
    object = Class.new attributes
    raise unless object.save!
  end 
rescue
  puts object.error.full_messages # Why can't we use local varible inside rescue ?
end
```

Instance Variable

```
begin
  transaction  #Code inside transaction 
    @object = Class.new attributes
    raise unless @object.save!
  end 
rescue
  puts @object.error.full_messages # This is working fine.
end
```

Comment: The first one works for me, whether I assign to the variable inside or outside the `begin ... rescue` block.

Comment: @Antal I am using transaction inside begin block and i have defined object inside transaction. Can it cause the problem? I have updated my question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You most certainly can access local variables defined in a `begin`, in the corresponding `rescue` block (assuming of course, the exception has been raised, after the variable was set).

What you can't do is access local variables that are defined inside a block, outside of the block. This has nothing to do with exceptions. See this simple example:

```
define transaction() yield end
transaction do
  x = 42
end
puts x # This will cause an error because `x` is not defined here.
```

What you can do to fix this, is to define the variable before the block (you can just set it to nil) and then set it inside the block.

```
x = nil
transaction do
  x = 42
end
puts x # Will print 42
```

So if you change your code like this, it will work:

```
begin
  object = nil
  transaction do  #Code inside transaction 
    object = Class.new attributes
    raise unless object.save!
  end 
rescue
  puts object.error.full_messages # Why can't we use local varible inside rescue ?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up error message from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid. It can be seen on official document example here.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html

```
begin
  transaction
    Class.create! attributes
  end 
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
  puts invalid.record.error.full_messages
end
```